# PHP Leftmost digit

Tags: php, digits

let's say I have a variable containing an integer or a float (since integers might overflow into a float in PHP).

I want to run some operation to get the leftmost digit and the rest of the remaining digits.

To explain better:

```
<?php

$x   = NULL;  //this will hold first digit
$num = 12345; //int

/// run operation


//outputs
//$x   = 1;
//$num = 2345;
var_dump($x, $num);

?>
```

Now, I know there's multitudes of ways to do this if you represent the number as a string, but I'm trying to avoid type casting it into a string.

I'm probably looking for a solution which includes bitwise operations, but I'm pretty weak in that topic so I'm hoping someone who usually works low-level might be able to answer this!

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Purpose of that task would surely help.

Comment: What you are looking for is integer division and the modulo operator.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: A bit complicated to justify, but simply put, I want to loop over each digit from left to right.

@Ranieri: I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Avoids using any string manipulation, but no guarantees for float or even negative values

```
$x   = NULL;  //this will hold first digit
$num = 12345; //int

$m = 1;
while(true) {
    $m *= 10;
    if ($m > $num)
        break;
}

$m /= 10;

$x = (int) floor($num / $m);
$num = $num % $m;


//outputs
//$x   = 1;
//$num = 2345;
var_dump($x, $num);
```

Comment: If you want to work with float as well, then you'll need to replace $num = $num % $m; with $num = fmod($num,$m);

Comment: I don't understand why casting the string to string and back is out of the question, but +1 for an answer that does what the OP wants.

Comment: I want to benchmark the difference between mathematical solution / string manipulation. I know, optimization is the root of all evil, but I'm working on thousands of numbers and I got some extra time to fool around.

Comment: I'd wager that string manipulation would be faster, but you might want to look at micro-optimising the while loop before running any performance tests because that's not particularly efficient

Comment: From my own testing:
`return floor($num/pow(10,(floor((log10($num))))));` takes 0.000005seconds and `return (int)substr($num, 0, 1);` takes 0.000004seconds. Size of the number does not show any change in processing time.

Answer (score 11):

I'm sure there is a way to do this without casting it to a string, but why? The `string` detour is so easy:

```
$x = (int)substr($num, 0, 1);
```

It'll give you a nice, proper integer.

Obviously, this does no extended checking for faulty input, and requires `$num` to be a valid number.

Comment: PHP Manual: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use square brackets instead, such as $str[42].

Comment: For -ve num, decimal number, your solution wil not work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7413381/2736817

Answer (score 8):

Math-only method:

```
function leftMost($num) {  
    return floor($num/pow(10,(floor((log10($num))))));
}
```

explained I guess...

1+ log10 of num calculates the number of digits a number is, we floor it to remove any decimal values, put it as the exponent so for a 1 digit number we get 10^0=1, or a 8 digit number we get 10^8. We then are just divding 12345678/10000000 = 1.2345678, which gets floor'd and is just 1.

note: this works for numbers between zero and one also, where it will return the 2 in 0.02, and a string transform will fail.

If you want to work with negative numbers, make $num = abs($num) first.

Comment: I get the result 881 from `$num = 12345`.

Comment: Sorry, I used 10^ instead of pow().

Comment: This does not work for negative numbers or 0. You should use abs($num) to guarantee it is positive and return 0 for the special case of 0. Alternatively, you could throw an error if $num <= 0?

Comment: @adamnfish I mentioned that in one of my edits. Also, zero is the worst number of all time. ALL TIME. -- Reason it doesn't work for 0, because log10(0) is at negative infinity.

Comment: Your solution is great, though the correct answer had to go to Mark Baker since he showed how to get the remaining digits as well. That said, thanks a lot for your solution!

Comment: Wait, why does `10^` not work but `pow()` works? What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

To get the rest of the digits

> $remainingnum = (int)substr((string)$num, 1, strlen($num));

Answer (score 0):

If you typcast the value to a string you can use the array type selector.

For example:

```
$n = (string)12345676543.876543;
echo (int)$n[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Baker offered the best solution, though you should do `abs(floor($num))` before applying the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I know you stated you wanted to avoid casting to a string, but if you want to loop over the digits in PHP, this will be the fastest way:

```
$len = strlen($n);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
  $d = $n[$i];
```

In a quick-and-dirty benchmark, it was around 50% faster than the equivalent set of mathematical expressions, even when minimizing the calls to `log` and `exp`.