# How can I separate a number and get the first two digits in PHP?

Tags: php

How can I separate a number and get the first two digits in PHP?

For example: `1345` -> I want this output=> `13` or `1542` I want `15`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

one possibility would be to use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php):

```
echo substr($mynumber, 0, 2);
```

**EDIT:**
please not that, like [hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre) said, this will break for negative numbers or small numbers with decimal places. his solution is the better one, as he's doing some checks to avoid this.

Comment: This is pretty fragile ([Demo](http://codepad.org/ogARCT6r)) and does the job only under certain circumstances.

Comment: Can i get your help regard same case https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205573/php-how-to-use-check-with-function     @oezi

Answer (score 9):

First of all you need to normalize your number, because not all numbers in PHP consist of digits only. You might be looking for an integer number:

```
$number = (int) $number;
```

Problems you can run in here is the range of integer numbers in PHP or rounding issues, see [Integers <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), `INF` comes to mind as well.

As the number now is an integer, you can use it in string context and extract the first two characters which will be the first two digits if the number is not negative. If the number is negative, the sign needs to be preserved:

```
$twoDigits = substr($number, 0, $number < 0 ? 3 : 2);
```

See the [Demo](http://codepad.org/v6yAqy10).

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't be too hard? A simple substring should do the trick (you can treat numbers as strings in a loosely typed language like PHP).

See the PHP manual page for the [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

Something like this:

```
$output = substr($input, 0, 2); //get first two characters (digits)
```

Comment: Any help https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205573/php-how-to-use-check-with-function @Spudley

Answer (score 2):

You can get the string value of your number then get the part you want using 
 [substr](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: There's no need for explicit type conversion in PHP. substr will do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

this should do what you want

```
$length = 2;
$newstr = substr($string, $lenght);
```

Answer (score 1):

With strong type-hinting in new version of PHP (> PHP 7.3) you can't use `substr` on a function if you have integer or float. Yes, you can cast as string but it's not a good solution.
You can divide by some ten factor and recast to int.

```php
$number = 1345; 
$mynumber = (int)($number/100);
echo $mynumber;
```

Display: 13

Comment: This requires that you first determine how many digits the number has.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use substr you can divide your number by 10 until it has 2 digits:

```
<?php
function foo($i) {
    $i = abs((int)$i);
    while ($i > 99)
        $i = $i / 10;
    return $i;
}
```

will give you first two digits

Comment: Make that while(abs($i) > 99) then you also take care of the negative case dealt with by @hakre with substr