# PHP - How to use check with function?

Tags: php, if-statement

Following are my PHP variables with values,

```
$value = 234333;

$value = 344665;

$value = 456325;
```

How to check if **number start with** 2 or 3 or 4.

If value start with 2 print "this is 2"

If value start with 3 print "this is 3"

If value start with 4 print "this is 4"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I separate a number and get the first two digits in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413190/how-can-i-separate-a-number-and-get-the-first-two-digits-in-php)

Comment: You can use preg_match. https://3v4l.org/KYUr0

Comment: Can you pls help me with further steps https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205573/php-how-to-use-check-with-function @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the value as a `string` and then use `substr` to check the first character.

Something like this would suffice:

```
function checkStartsWith($value) {
    $result = "";

    switch (substr($value, 0, 1)) {
        case "2":
        case "3":
        case "4":
            $result = "this is " . substr($value, 0, 1);
            break;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

How you *could* call it:

```
echo checkStartsWith(234333);
echo checkStartsWith(344665);
echo checkStartsWith(456325);
```

Outputs:

```
this is 2
this is 3
this is 4
```

Comment: Seems like overkill code wize :) Couldn't you just do `"this is " . substr($value, 0, 1);` and save a function call and a complete switch :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly You could but only if you wanted the first digital always. My understanding from the question was that the value was only output when the number started with 2, 3, or 4.  Perhaps I misunderstoood the requirement?

Comment: @RiggsFolly From OP: _How to check if **number start with** 2 or 3 or 4._

Comment: Yup, missed that :)

Comment: @Martin I just want to apply above script to my another function, could you pls help me with that https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205573/php-how-to-use-check-with-function